# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, dictionary

- I am trying to copy a json into another dictionary, trying to make a copy as I will be computing some values and adding it to the dictionary which I will be further sending to another function.
- I am trying to add it to the `dict` which I have defined, but not able to put the nested list `documents` into the dictionary which is throwing error.
- Code

```
    import json
    
    sample_json = """{
      "CallbackURL": "<callback-url>",
      "UseCaseCode": "CM",
      "UserCode": "<user>",
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "documents": [
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string1>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A1.json",
          "ContextKey": "A1.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string2>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A2.json",
          "ContextKey": "A2.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string3>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A3.json",
          "ContextKey": "A3.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string4>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A4.json",
          "ContextKey": "A4.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        }
      ],
      "ClientCode": "CL",
      "Source": "Client"
    }"""
    
    ldict_new_transaction_msg = dict({tuple([])})
    
    item_dict = json.loads(sample_json)
    print(item_dict['documents'][0]['Object'])
    print(len(item_dict['documents']))
    
    ldict_new_transaction_msg['documents'][0]['Object'] = item_dict['documents'][0]['Object']
```

- Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

- Expected Output, the fields `"NoOfFiles", "CsvDoc", "PdfDoc",` , are being calculated on run time with some other function, that's why  I am creating a copy of the present dictionary.

```
    {
      "CallbackURL": "<callback-url>",
      "UseCaseCode": "CM",
      "UserCode": "<user>",
      "ObjectType": "Document",
      "documents": [
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string1>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A1.json",
          "ContextKey": "A1.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string2>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A2.json",
          "ContextKey": "A2.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string3>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A3.json",
          "ContextKey": "A3.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        },
        {
          "Object": "<base-64-string4>",
          "ObjectSourceFileName": "A4.json",
          "ContextKey": "A4.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
          "ObjectFormat": "csv"
        }
      ],
      "ClientCode": "CL",
      "Source": "Client",
      "NoOfFiles": "<count>",
      "CsvDoc": "<count>",
      "PdfDoc": "<count>",
      "XmlDoc": "<count>"
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `ldict_new_transaction_msg = dict({tuple([])})` - what should this line do?

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Consider searching for similar problems before asking.

Comment: @David trying to create a list inside dictionary for the required structure, should it be just ```ldict_new_transaction_msg={}``` but i need to have a list inside dictionary.

Comment: You can just go with `ldict_new_transaction_msg = item_dict.copy()` to create an exact copy of the dictionary, then manipulate the new one.